# Handling the back browser button while iterating through a list

Tags: jsf

I have a list that I iterate through and fill in the fields one page at a a time. I'm using an array list and I increment a counter everytime the user clicks the next button.

This works well. The problem comes when a user wants to go back and edit the previous entries. The counter stays the same and the current user in the backing bean gets updated with the users input. The user at [counter] in the array list then gets updated and instead of the one that was navigated to.

Any ideas how I can implement this? If I could intercept the submit button and update the current user with the user in focus then I could update the current id manually and save to that slot. Any other ideas? I hope this makes sense.

Thanks
Wayne

Answer (score 1):

It's not much of an answer but it will have to do for now. I've referenced the id from the array list directly and created 10 different pages which only load if the array list is large enough. It works for me because 10 is a maximum. If any of you have a better solution I'd love to hear it.